# helm using argument in template to check if value exists in Values.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

The problem is following: I want to check if field in Values.yaml exists based on argument given to the template in _helpers.tpl:

```
{{- define "example-name" -}}
{{- $objectRef := index . 0 -}}
{{- if .Values.custom -}}
{{- if .Values.custom.$objectRef -}}
{{- if .Values.custom.$objectRef.annotations -}}
{{- include "some-library" (tuple .Values.custom.$objectRef.annotations) | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

Then in my deployment for example:

```
{{- template "example-name" "someField" }}
```

I want the result to be following:

```
{{- define "example-name" -}}
{{- $objectRef := index . 0 -}}
{{- if .Values.custom -}}
{{- if .Values.custom.someField-}}
{{- if .Values.custom.someField.annotations -}}
{{- include "some-library" (tuple .Values.custom.someField.annotations) | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

But the only thing I get is following error: bad character U+0024 '$'
I want to use template multiple times with various arguments. I haven't seen anyone dealing with the same problem before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The [standard template function](https://pkg.go.dev/text/template) you're looking for is `index`.  In its simplest form, `index $map $key` does a dynamic lookup of the `$key` (can be any expression) in the provided `$map` (can be any expression).  It can also do integer-index lookups in arrays (Go slices) and nested lookups if you need to.

The other problem that you'll run into is that `$map.undefinedKey` (or `index $map "undefinedKey"`), assuming `undefinedKey` is not present in `$map`, is valid but evaluates to Go `nil`.  So you can't do further lookups in that.  The workaround to this I typically use is to use the Helm (Sprig) [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) function to use an empty [`dict`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#dict) if a value is not present.

That would give you a template like:

```yaml
{{- define "example-name" -}}
{{- $top := index . 0 -}}
{{- $objectRef := index . 1 -}}
{{- $custom := $top.Values.custom | default dict -}}
{{- $object := index $custom $objectRef | default dict -}}
{{- with $object.annotations -}}
{{- include "some-library" (list $top .) | indent 4 }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

This is called with a list of *two* values, the top-level Helm object and a reference to a key in `.Values.custom`

```yaml
{{- include "example-name" (list . "someField") -}}
```

The template extracts the two values from the list parameter.  It then traverses the values structure one level at a time, at each level defaulting to an empty dictionary.  So for example if there is no `.Values.custom` then `$custom` is set to an empty dictionary, which allows `index $custom $objectRef` to execute successfully (and return `nil`, but not abort).  At the bottom level we use the `with` template function to check to see if come value is truthy, and if so, temporarily bind `.` to its value.  When we make the inner call, we already have the top-level Helm object in a variable, and we can assemble a list of `$top` and the non-empty annotation structure `.` as the single template parameter.